# HTTP website behind HTTPS Let's Encrypt NGINX Route

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, blazor

I can't seem to figure out if this is common practice or not, but I want to create a website (Running on a container) and then have traffic forwarded to the website from a wildcard on my domain, I want to secure it and use Nginx Proxy Manager and Let's Encrypt to manage the certificate.

Do I keep the website running on my internal server as just HTTP:80 and redirect traffic to to via Nginx? My current site is just a serverside Blazor webapp.

I've seen other people do this, but it makes me wonder if that is indeed secure, at some point between Nginx and the internal server it is not encrypted. Is my understanding correct?

I imagine it looks something like this:

Client connects securely to Nginx Proxy Manager (HTTPS)
Nginx Proxy Manager then decrypts and forwards to the Internal Website (HTTP)

Is my understanding correct?

Is this common practice, or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: the container shouldn't be accessible from outside on any port then its fine to do user -> nginx 443 (Lets encrypt) -> app 80 (or any other port), you could do ssl all the way through but its not needed unless other containers on the host are not under your control, if not you then should do it else its open to mitm

Comment: Thanks, yeah the whole environment is under my control, but I was just wondering if I should be doing end-to-end encryption. I don't like the idea that at some point traffic is being decrypted and then plain-text stuff is travelling around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like the best answer was from Lawrence Cherone.

> The container shouldn't be accessible from outside on any port then
> its fine to do user -> nginx 443 (Lets encrypt) -> app 80 (or any
> other port), you could do ssl all the way through but its not needed
> unless other containers on the host are not under your control, if not
> you then should do it else its open to mitm